# Date format conversion of cvs column to table column using SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, dataflow

I am using SSIS package to import data from cvs file to table.

```
CVS File

Report_Date
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
20140125
```

I want to convert in to 2014-02-05 date format.How can i do that in ssis Package.I tried with convert and casting but i was not successfull.Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONVERT(` function to change that into date. For example

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'20140210',112)
```

After you change it into date you can output it into any format that you want.

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for list of all styles that you can use for `DATE` when converting it. `112` stands for `yyyymmdd` format.

if date is stored as Numeric field you will need to convert it to VARCHAR before converting it to DATE,

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),20140204),112)
```

Comment: i had tried above query in my column transfomation but i am getting error.

Comment: This is likely from SQL Server interpreting it as numeric field, instead of string. In that case just convert it to Varchar before trying to parse it as date.

Comment: Thanks guys i got the answer by using below expression (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Report_Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Report_Date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Report_Date],7,2))

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it with SSIS but if you look at TSQL output of these queries

```
Select Cast(20140125 AS DATETIME)

Select Cast('20140125' AS DATETIME)
```

First one failed with "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."
But second succeed.. It means if you convert first it to string and then to DateTime, it should work.. Will update you if able to do directly from SSIS

Comment: Can we use select statements in column transformation.I tried with above query ( SELECT cast( '[Report_Date]' as  DATETIME))

Answer (score 1):

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Report_Date],1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Report_Date],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Report_Date],7,2))
```